# image background removal/masking before multiclass classification - ideas?

Tags: image-processing, background, classification

I am working on a hyperspectral image with a number of known sample classes + background, trying to classify the samples correctly as one material or another, total of maybe 2 - 15 different materials. The background is more or less homogeneous. According to tests I need to identify and skip any background first and then only classify against the materials to improve the performance instead of treating background as one additional class among others.

The question is: how would one do a background identification efficiently and with high reliability? In some cases a simple thresholding will work fine but not always. The homogenous nature of the background could also offer an option.

Trying to search this topic brings up a ton of background identification discussion in object detection and classification, which is not what I want.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you post some example pictures for us to play around with? If the background is smooth you might be able to use edge detection to find and crop objects on top of it.

Comment: I thought of that as an alternative approach: not finding the background but objects on the background. If we just can do it fast enough for real-time applications.

Will PNGs or other similar do as examples? The hyperspectral sets tend to be a bit larger as they have something like 200 bands for each pixel.

Comment: give any set of pictures that you think represents a good sample of the challenges you're facing (i.e. if we can come up with a solution that can catch all of the samples then it should be good on the rest of the images).

Comment: For anyone interesting at looking a bit more, I have uploaded a small test data set here, together with a desription of it and a png image to show how it should look:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7e839fd9e976c241d0b2a557a25d983920210210100203/aec134

This data is very clean and contains only a single type of objects. These can be easily separated from the background by e.g. thresholding. But there are cases with e.g. 12 different types of objects where the background separation from the objects does not work as well at least not using PLS-DA, and not perfect using SVM either.